# Unable to upload file using sendKeys on input element

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In order to avoid window dialog of upload file, I'm trying following:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ab-attachment-item']/input")).sendKeys(filePath);
```

Following is the HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="ab-attachments">
  <span class="ab-attachment-item" ng-hide="isReadOnly()" style="background-color: transparent;">
    <input class="ab-attachment-input ng-isolate-scope firefinder-match" type="file" rx-file-upload="file" accept=".pdf,image/*" style="background-color: transparent;">
```

But it results into error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I want to confirm if this error is because of `ng-hide="isReadOnly()"` in `span` tag?

And how this can be resolved using Selenium WebDriver itself(using JavaScriptExecutor or something)?

For handling this dialog other tools like Sikuli, AutoIt can be used; but I want to avoid that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("ab-attachment-input ng-isolate-scope firefinder-match")).sendKeys(filePath);
```

If not try adding an implicit wait before you try and `sendKeys`

```
Int timeoutInSeconds = 10;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("ab-attachment-input ng-isolate-scope firefinder-match"));
```

Comment: TidusJar,  I tried this as well but it gives error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of....`

Comment: The reason why that would be happening is that the WebDriver Wait cannot find the element. That tells me you are not correctly locating the element.

Comment: If I hadn't located element correctly, it would not have given error: `org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with` at first place rather it would have given error: `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element:` Checking visibility of element happens only if element is found.

Comment: Since you are doing an implicit wait before interacting with the element, that is where it is timing out. It cannot find the element within the timeout period 10 Seconds.

Answer (score 0):

//I would use implicit wait and directly call the input element instead

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("[rx-file-upload='file'][accept=".pdf,image/*"]"))).sendKeys("filePathWithExtension");
```

Comment: Saifur, I tried this as well but it gives error: `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of....`

Comment: BTW is that a visible element though? if so use `findelEmens()` to see how many elements it returns. I suspect there are multiple elements and the selector is nor finding the correct one.

Comment: This makes good sense. Saifur, I tried that and it returns `1` means that is the only element. Might be that is not visible because of `ng-hide="isReadOnly()"` in `span` tag as I mentioned in the question.